# Challenges to DIY a USB QC 3.0 charger for a DJI Mavic Pro @ 13V?

Tags: usb, battery-charging

One of the big pain points with all of the DJI Mavic Pro drones is that they do not charge via USB. In order to charge the batteries you have to buy an AC-DC adapter which adds a good amount of extra weight and bulk to something that could just otherwise be a single USB-C cable.

https://store.dji.com/product/mavic-50w-battery-charger-without-ac-cable

The charger outputs 13.05 V at 3.83 A. Since QC 3.0 can go up to 20V and 18W, it could output 13.00V at 1.4A, slower than the stock charger but vastly simplifying the charging hardware.

How difficult would it be to hack together the DJI battery's charging plug into a USB-C cable that somehow directs the QC 3.0 power adapter to only provide 13V?

I'm assuming that the current will actually be controlled by the DJI battery, right?  So if the DJI battery tries to pull 3.83A it would fry the QC 3.0 charger?

Comment: it is unclear what you are saying ..... you cannot charge anything with just a USB-C cable ..... you still require an AC-DC adapter to supply the power, no matter what kind of cable you use

Comment: The DJI charger is a 100-240V AC to 13.05V DC adapter with proprietary cables and a big power brick since it supplies 50W. I want to use something like an 18W QC 3.0 charger and 'set' it to provide 13V and hack together a cable with one end that terminates at the proprietary DJI connector and another that terminates in USB.

Comment: What is so proprietary with the standard AC cable? The whole thing looks like an ordinary 50W brick...and not very expensive one.

Comment: How are we supposed to give you an advice to interface **proprietary** QC 3.0 protocol with **proprietary** DJI charger interface? Nobody officially knows anything about details of either of them.

Comment: There is no certainty that the MP system will allow a lower wattage charger to work. Some systems attempt to load the charger at a designed current level and if the source voltage sags below limits will not charge.

Comment: There is practically no difference between 13.05V and 13.00V. The smart load determines what it needs and the smart supply will limit the current upto 3.83 A @13.05 V.  It is not hard.

Comment: is the connector the same as these?  https://store.dji.com/product/mavic-battery-charging-hub-advanced?from=compatibility

Comment: Are you sure that the DJI charger just outputs 13V @ 3.8A, and doesn't also have advanced charging circuitry in it?  Because that multipin connector makes me think it might be a balance charger that needs connections between cells within the battery.